# Call a method (with an argument) after a delay

Tags: c#

I want to pass a variable into a function that is run after a delay. I've seen similar question on how to do this (see below). I dont think this is what I want as I each time `method1` is called, the number of attached anonymous functions grows? What I need to do is remove any existing attached anonymous function before adding the new one. But I dont think this possible. Is there a way to call a method after a delay but pass in a new value of a variable each time?

```
using System.Timers;

myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.Interval = 3000;
myTimer.AutoReset = false;

public void method1(int var1){
    myTimer.Elapsed += delegate { doSomething(var1); };
    myTimer.Start();
}

public void doSomething(int arg1){...}
```

**UPDATE**

Basically whenever `method1` is run, I want something to happen 3 secs later, and I need to pass in an argument that may vary each time.

I dont think I can use a field to store the variable because `method1` may be called several times before the first timer expires. I.e. there could be several qued up. E.g. at one point in time the que of 'doSomething' waiting to happen could be...

```
doSomething(3)
doSomething(7)
doSomething(1)
```

It is just used in a testbench, and `method1` will be run called no more than 50 times. What I want to ensure is that each `doSomething(var1)` only gets called once and not every 3 secs. Ie there is only one `doSomething` called each time `method1` is called.

This is for a windows console app.

Comment: Why don't you move your parameter to a field and use it as shared resource?

Comment: @Redwan, cant do that, I've update my question.

Comment: What kind of data is in the variable?  Are you wanting to execute the same logic each time against different data or possibly execute different logic even?

Comment: You haven't actually expalined how you want this to function.  So when someone calls the method, and then calls it again in 1 second, what should happen?  Should it call `doSomething` on just the second value of `var1`?  If so, when should it call it, in 2 seconds, or in three?

Comment: @spiderplant0 What's wrong with field? I can't understand. You want the last value to be passed as argumet when `doSomething` called or all the values which was called with `methodRunRegularly`?

Comment: Your requirements are very badly phrased. It seems like you want `doSomething()` to run *periodically* rather than after a delay? Should it pick up whatever the current value is when it runs, or does each iteration get a different value (e.g. from a queue)? Perhaps if you tried explaining the purpose of this function instead?

Comment: Are you providing the values in advance or on the fly?

Comment: @James World, etc, I've update the question. Basically whenever method1 is run, I want something to happen 3 secs later, and I need to pass in an argument that may vary each time.

Comment: @James World, values will be known just before method1 is called

Comment: My answer should see you right simply then, you'll need Microsoft's [reactive extensions](http://rx.codeplex.com) - but there are lots of advantages to using that, especially for testing anything time related.

Answer (score 5):

Using the TPL (& .Net 4.5), you can do something like this:

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static async void DelayFor(this Action act, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        act();
    }
}

//usage
Action toDo = () => doSomething(var1);
toDo.DelayFor(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

... or this may be simpler for your app:

```
static async void DoSomethingLater(int n)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    //DoSomething(n);
}

//usage
void Method1(int n)
{
    DoSomethingLater(n);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah! I haven't "baked in" `Task.Delay` yet... nice one. async *void* though? :o! Still + 1

Comment: Yeah, I don't have enough context but it feels like `Method1` is an event handler and `async void` _should_ be ok.

Answer (score 3):

There's no good way to do that using `System.Timers.Timer`.

With `System.Threading.Timer`, you can pass a `userState` object to the constructor. That object is then passed to the timer callback with every tick. For example:

```
string Whatever = "foo";
System.Threading.Timer timer = 
    new System.Threading.Timer(MyTimerCallback, whatever, 100, 100);

void MyTimerCallback (object state)
{
    string theData = (string)state;
    // at this point, theData is a reference to the "Whatever" string.
    // do tick processing
}
```

You could, if you want, extend `System.Timers.Timer`, and add a property to hold your data. Something like:

```
class DerivedTimer : System.Timers.Timer
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

myTimer = new DerivedTimer();
myTimer.Interval = 3000;

public void methodRunRegularly(int var1){
    myTimer.Foo = "Foobar!";
    myTimer.Elapsed += doSomething;
    myTimer.Start();
}

public void doSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var t = (DerivedTimer)sender;
    var foo = t.Foo;
    // do processing
}
```

A reference to the timer is passed in the `sender` parameter. You can just cast that and then reference the `Foo` property that you set when you initialized the timer.

Answer (score 3):

This makes use of Reactive Extensions (use nuget package "rx-main").

Run a method with a 3 second delay:

```
public void method1(int value)
{
    ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance.Schedule(
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () => doSomething(value));
}
```

That's about as short as it gets!